# .xlms Excel file error while uploading using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I try to upload a `.xlms` file, but when i click upload and after i click button

My program doesn't come in debugging mode or upload the file

Check this image below please

[image]

So why if i upload a `.xls` file it works, but if it is a `.xmls` file it displays that error.

Thanks

Comment: The two file types you are testing are quite different, `.xls` is the old MS Excel binary file format while `.xlms` is the Office Open XML format, in this case with macros embedded in the file (otherwise it would be `.xlsx`). Does your tool's documentation say it can handle the new file format (MS Excel 2007 - 2013)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your .xmls file bigger than 4 MB? Try to adjust the following attribute value in web.config.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
```